# google-wallet post back decoding errors

Tags: php, postback, android-pay, jwt

My post back file for googlw-wallet digital goods is failing. I know i get a valid respose from google as i put in a test line to check i get a response that emailed the response to myself. As  tested I got a correct jwt decoded (using googles on line jwt decoder) as below. When I moved the test line to below the JWT::decode line I don't get a response indicating a fatal error in the decode which is unaltered from the jwt (by luciferous). When I run the postback myself I get the fatal errors (no jwt posted of course) indicating the includes and scripts are being found.

The returned post back is 
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.PV8c18EGWLL38sUDmjMY1HEV91An6ZVnKkymuW2SQUI.

```
header
   {
    "alg": "HS256"
   }
claims
    {
    "aud": "12345605871924644272", 
    "iss": "Google", 
    "request": {
        "currencyCode": "GBP", 
        "price": "100", 
        "sellerData": "ghhk,ghty.com,Invoice Number:106597", 
        "name": "Invoice Number: 106597", 
        "description": "Supported Service"
    }, 
    "exp": 1415024854, 
    "iat": 1415024834, 
    "typ": "google/payments/inapp/item/v1/postback/buy", 
    "response": {
        "orderId": "GWDG_S.ceabb5c4-5956-48b2-a40b-7fc2dd184a9a"
    }
   }
signature
   PV8c18EGWLL38njyujMY1HEV91An6ZVnKkymuW2SQUI
```

I am getting a fatal error when trying to decode as i cant get to a test line after.

my post back script is

```
<?php

    require_once '../../includes/lib/JWT.php';
    require_once '../../includes/seller_info_test.php';



    $encoded_jwt = $_POST['jwt'];

     $decodedJWT  = JWT::decode($encoded_jwt, $sellerSecret);
     $orderId     = $decodedJWT->response->orderId;

     header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
     echo $orderId;

     $logfile = "purchasing/logfile.txt";
     if (!file_exists($logfile)) {
        touch($logfile);
        chmod($logfile, 0777);
     }
     $orderIDS   = file($logfile); //reads file into array
     $orderIDS[] = $orderId; //append new orderID to array
     file_put_contents($logfile, $orderIDS); //save the new array to file
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem now resolved. very simple $sellerSecret was not being read from the include file when replaced with the actual value it worked. Look for the obvious i suppose! log file lines removed and an a send email include added. Next step to write include file to write response data back to database against seller data field.